# Plunkr + Angular2 + Router + Browser Url Change

Tags: angular, url-routing, plunker

I'm trying to create a Plunkr using angular2 and the router.  I actually have it working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mU0iS0g68G6vEdAokSNd?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><br/><router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
@Routes([
{path:'/page-one',component:PageOneComponent },
{path:'/page-two',component:PageTwoComponent }
{path:'*',component:PageOneComponent }
])
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(public router:Router){

  }
}
```

My problem is that when I run my app on my machine, the URL will change in the browser when I change routes (e.g. to something like http://localhost/page-one ) but in the plunkr, the url in the browser never changes when I change routes - it just stays as the same plunkr.co/edic/blahblahblah.  Is there a way to view/edit/control the 'url' that the app using the router sees within the plunkr?

## UPDATE

To give a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish, im trying to reproduce a bug with the router using plunkr as requested in this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8603#issuecomment-218953090

Comment: For example, you can use location.path() http://plnkr.co/edit/fUZ08lLfP7UGdp07KxN8?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui...It still doesn't make any sense. not working !

Comment: @Tucker http://take.ms/EKfMe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a plunker you must open the plunker in an external window:

[image]

Then the plunker will open in a window that will show you the URL changes you expect. See below:

[image]

Comment: i like this, but when I add url parameters, it breaks the page- e.g.: http://run.plnkr.co/rIx0xQPac8ntUHii?something=value0  Im trying to reproduce a bug in the router (see updated question) to give insight in what I'm trying to do